# functionalities of continue/ break on the code in Python and its output

Tags: python, if-statement, break, continue

For the following programs, I know that they are not valid but I'm asking the logic of the code. I don't mean to run this code, just to know the output that It shall print, and the functionalities of continue/ break. I'd appreciate your feedback/comment/concern on this.

```
for x in [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]:
    if 1 < x < 13:
        continue
    else:
        print x
```

Shouldn't the output to be : 2,3,5,8 since they are in the 1< x< 13 range? what does the continue does in this code? does it change the outcome?

```
found = False
for n in xrange(40,50):
    if (n / 45) > 1:
        found = True
        break
print found
```

I think it would print out 46, 47, 48, 49, 50. but that break in the code, does it simply make a pause on the process?

Comment: `continue` means "skip the rest of this turn and continue the loop from the next turn". `break` means "exit the whole loop".

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the comment. I get that, then the 2nd one would print out True, I suppose?

Comment: @khelwood and the first one would print out 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13? since it is just print x

Comment: @khelwood thanks in advance for correcting me

Comment: " and the first one would print out 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13? "  -- No it wouldn't. See my first comment.

Comment: the first loop prints only the items not satisfying the condition, i.e. 1, 1, 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop, the `continue` statement **skips** the rest of the loop body, to 'continue' with the next iteration. Since `1` and `13` do not match the `1 < x < 13` chained comparison, only the first 2 and the last value are actually printed, the rest are skipped.

Not that `continue` matters here, the `print` is only executed in the `else` suite *anyway*; you may as well use `pass` instead of `continue`:

```
for x in [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]:
    if 1 < x < 13:
        pass
    else:
        print x
```

or use `if not (1 < x < 13): print x`.

In the second loop, the `break` *ends* the loop altogether. No numbers are printed (there is no `print n` anywhere), just `False` printed by the `print found` statement. That's because in Python 2 `/` with integers only gives you *floor division* so the `if` statement never becomes true (only if `n = 90` or larger would `n / 45` ever become `2` or greater).

A better illustration of the two statements would be to use `print` before the loop, in the loop before and after the statements, and printing afterwards, so you can see what code is executed when:

```
print 'Before the loop'
for i in range(5):
    print 'Start of the loop, i = {}'.format(i)
    if i == 2:
        print 'i is set to 2, continuing with the next iteration'
        continue
    if i == 3:
        print 'i is set to 3, breaking out of the loop'
        break
    print 'End of the loop'
print 'Loop has completed'
```

which outputs:

```
Start of the loop, i = 0
End of the loop
Start of the loop, i = 1
End of the loop
Start of the loop, i = 2
i is set to 2, continuing with the next iteration
Start of the loop, i = 3
i is set to 3, breaking out of the loop
Loop has completed
```

Note that there is no `End of the loop` following `i = 2`, and there is no `i = 4` at all.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` causes the program to skip to the next iteration of the loop. Hence, the first block would print 1 1 13 since those are the only elements that don't satisfy the `if` condition.

`break` terminates a loop, so the second snippet's loop seems as though it should terminate at 46. However, since integer division in python only retains the whole part, this loop will continue uninterrupted till the end of the range.